# How to calculate test coverage if testing only URLs with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, koa

I use Jest with superset for testing working Koa's urls. All test placed in `__test__` folder and I testing only request urls from my routes.
How can I use coverage for mark testing routes? Maybe I can use something special comments in routing source file or use some middleware for mark working routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually test coverage implies which part of code that your test imports was actually executed.

In your case it sounds like you are doing integration testing, and you want to know how many endpoints out of all endpoints are working.

If integration testing is what you really want, you could have an sdk of sorts, and then track line coverage of that. Separate your testing network requests from your integration tests.

Comment: Thank you for this point. Yes, I want to test my endpoints. You wrote about sdk. Could you tell me, how is this case working? Maybe JS have some tools for this? Or convention how I should mark my working endpoints after testing it?

Comment: The more I think about, in your case coverage is dependent on number of tests vs number of endpoints. So, if say you have 2 tests and 4 endpoints, that's 50% coverage. Or if you have 4 tests, but 1 of them fail, that's kinda like 75%.

Comment: I understand this) But do you know any automatic lib for this?

Comment: I don't think there are any. Because every endpoint is a unique little snowflake :D